# Windows Server 2012 show console output of existing process

Tags: command-line, windows-server-2012-r2

A virtual machine is automatically provisioned and a command line process is launched with standard output to a stdout.txt.

How can I attach a real-time console window to it while it is running?

Comment: Which VM software are you using?

Comment: @LPChip Honestly, I don't know. These are in Azure. Probably some variation of standalone Hyper V. I can log in remotely through the RDP client.

Comment: Ah, so you have a Windows Server 2012 Nano then, which uses Hyper-V as base, but doesn't provide a GUI.